# Uncaught TypeError: this.groupItems() is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using [Responsive Mobile-first Image Viewer - jQuery SmartPhoto](https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Responsive-Mobile-first-Image-Viewer-jQuery-SmartPhoto.html) plugin on my website. I notice that If I use `jquery-2.2.4.min.js` then it's working and if I use the latest jQuery `jquery 3.5.1` then it's not working.

Sometimes I am getting an error on my console.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.groupItems() is undefined

**Old Jquery 3.5.1** not working

```js
$(function() {
  $(".js-img-viwer").smartPhoto();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Mobile-first-Image-Viewer-jQuery-SmartPhoto/css/smartphoto.min.css">
<div class="masonry">

  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/867/1997?image=510" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Jeff Sheldon" data-id="raion">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/829?image=510" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1716/1140?image=494" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Matthew Wiebe" data-id="rakuda">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/239?image=494" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1282/1929?image=482" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Danny Froese" data-id="kaba">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/541?image=482" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1716/1141?image=454" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Mia Domenico" data-id="koara">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/239?image=454" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1716/1141?image=449" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Maciej Serafinowicz" data-id="kuma">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/239?image=449" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1716/1140?image=445" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Aleksi Tappura" data-id="sai">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/239?image=445" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Mobile-first-Image-Viewer-jQuery-SmartPhoto/js/jquery-smartphoto.min.js?v=1"></script>
```

**Old Jquery 2.2.4** working

```js
$(function() {
  $(".js-img-viwer").smartPhoto();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Mobile-first-Image-Viewer-jQuery-SmartPhoto/css/smartphoto.min.css">
<div class="masonry">

  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/867/1997?image=510" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Jeff Sheldon" data-id="raion">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/829?image=510" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1716/1140?image=494" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Matthew Wiebe" data-id="rakuda">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/239?image=494" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1282/1929?image=482" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Danny Froese" data-id="kaba">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/541?image=482" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1716/1141?image=454" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Mia Domenico" data-id="koara">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/239?image=454" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1716/1141?image=449" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Maciej Serafinowicz" data-id="kuma">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/239?image=449" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1716/1140?image=445" class="js-img-viwer" data-caption="Aleksi Tappura" data-id="sai">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/360/239?image=445" width="360" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Mobile-first-Image-Viewer-jQuery-SmartPhoto/js/jquery-smartphoto.min.js?v=1"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this would change with newer jQuery-Version but since you want something done with your images:

Have you tried using jquery's window.onload instead of only `$()`-prefix?

`$()` is short for `$(document).ready()` which runs once DOM is ready, whereas `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` runs once things like images are also ready:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Do I need to use like this  $(window).on( "load", function() { $(".js-img-viwer").smartPhoto(); }); but it's not working

Comment: Yes like that. Must be some other problem then